# Chamar função de banco de dados que recebe uma lista como parametro

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot

Gente como faço o seguinte... envolve banco de dados (Postgres SQL) e JPA, quero criar uma função de banco de dados que recebe uma lista de ids como parâmetro e faça faça uma consulta cm a clausura WHERE IN (...). No JPA  como faço pra chamar essa função, e como passo essa lista de ids (Long)como parâmetro?  Ja tentei de tudo, pesquisei bastante mas n tive êxito.

Ex.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fnGetEmailUsuarios(ids int[])
RETURNS TABLE(email VARCHAR(40))
AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT u.email FROM usuario u WHERE u.tipo IN ids';
    END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A consulta dentro da função `public.fnGetEmailUsuarios( ids int[] )` possui um erro em sua cláusula `WHERE`.

O operador `IN()` espera uma lista de `scalar values` e sua função está passando para `IN()` um argumento do tipo `array`.

Você precisa de operadores capazes de receber valores do tipo `array`, tais como `SOME()` ou `ANY()`.

Assumindo que voce tenha algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE public.usuario
(
    id INTEGER,
    email VARCHAR(40),
    tipo INTEGER
);


INSERT INTO public.usuario ( id, email, tipo ) VALUES (1,'alpha@teste.com',    10);
INSERT INTO public.usuario ( id, email, tipo ) VALUES (2,'beta@teste.com',     20);
INSERT INTO public.usuario ( id, email, tipo ) VALUES (3,'gamma@teste.com',    30);
INSERT INTO public.usuario ( id, email, tipo ) VALUES (4,'delta@teste.com',    40);
INSERT INTO public.usuario ( id, email, tipo ) VALUES (5,'episilon@teste.com', 50);
```

Sua função deve ser reescrita da seguinte forma a fim de funcionar corretamente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fnGetEmailUsuarios(ids int[])
RETURNS TABLE(email VARCHAR(40))
AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT u.email FROM public.usuario u WHERE u.tipo = ANY ( ids );
    END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

O que possibilitaria consultas do tipo:

```
SELECT public.fnGetEmailUsuarios(  ARRAY[10,30,50] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Dá pra fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Objeto, Long> {     
    @Query("SELECT fnGetEmailUsuarios(:lista)")
    public List<Objeto> find(@Param("lista") String[] lista);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar assim:

```
public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long> {   
    List<Usuario> findByTipo(List<Integer> tipos);
}
```

E nas chamadas:

```
usuarioRepository.findByTipo(Arrays.asList(0, 1));
```